# calling script-local function in vim issues error?

Tags: vim, centos7

I am new learner of writing vim plugin and vimscripting and tried to customized my plugin for folding my code file with following custom functions.

```
setlocal foldmethod=indent
setlocal foldmethod=expr
setlocal foldexpr=<SID>FoldFunction(v:lnum)

function! s:GetNextNonBlankLine(lnum)
    let numlines = line('$')
    let current = a:lnum + 1

    while current <= numlines
        if getline(current) =~? '\v\S'
            return current
        endif

        let current += 1
    endwhile

    return -2
endfunction

function! s:FindIndentLevel(lnum)
    return indent(a:lnum) / &shiftwidth
endfunction

function! s:FoldFunction(lnum)
    if getline(a:lnum) =~? '\v^\s*$'
        return '-1'
    endif
    let this_indent = <SID>FindIndentLevel(a:lnum)
    let next_indent = <SID>FindIndentLevel(<SID>GetNextNonBlankLine(a:lnum))

    if next_indent == this_indent
        return this_indent
    elseif next_indent < this_indent
        return this_indent
    elseif next_indent > this_indent
        return '>' . next_indent
    endif
endfunction
```

If I remove script-local prefix (s:) then it is working fine but many has suggested to convert it to script-local function as global function scope is not appreciated.

So I rewrote it but it is giving following error:

> E81: Using <SID> not in a script context

What is going wrong?

Comment: Have you tried something like this: `setlocal foldexpr=call function('s:FoldFunction')(v:lnum)`?

Comment: @RuslanOsmanov: Good idea, unfortunately the syntax is off on several levels.

Comment: @RuslanOsmanov: Getting error as: E518: Unknown option: function('s:FoldFunction')(v:lnum)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, global functions are better avoided, especially if you distribute your plugin to other people. In your local Vim setup, name clashes probably can be avoided, but you'll never know about others.

Unfortunately, Vim only automatically handles script-local functions (i.e. the `<SID>` prefix) in mappings and commands, but not in assignment to options (like `'foldexpr'` here). This is a shortcoming of Vim.

An easy workaround would be using an **autoload script**. That is, move the `:function` definitions into (for example) `~/.vim/autoload/FoldUtil.vim`, and rename the function:

```
function! FoldUtil#FoldFunction(...)
```

Then, in your script, you just have this:

```
setlocal foldmethod=indent
setlocal foldmethod=expr
setlocal foldexpr=FoldUtil#FoldFunction(v:lnum)
```

With this, you also get all the other benefits of autoloading: The large script is only sourced once; you only execute the above 3 commands to enable the new folding method.

---

Note that you can derive the script's ID; you could then manually translate the id into the `<SNR>NNN_` that `<SID>` stands for. This would allow to keep the function script-local. But this is cumbersome, not needed here (as the autoload is the right solution), and it also sends a wrong signal (that the fold function is not meant to be stable and reusable) to other developers.

Comment: Is there any other way so that I can use this in the same folder where my other files and plugins scripts are there?

Comment: Instead of `~/.vim/autoload/FoldUtil.vim`, you can also put this in `~/.vim/plugin/FoldUtil.vim`; it's not lazily loaded then. Vim only checks that the function name corresponds to the script name, not whether it resides in `autoload`. Else, use a global function (but prefix it: `FoldUtil_FoldFunction()`; then you can put it anywhere.